# hyperledger Fabric - channel.tx and genesis.block very unclear

Tags: configuration, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, channel

Next week I'm starting on a new blockchain project using Hyperledger Fabric. I have a question regarding the configtx binary.

We use this binary to create a channel.tx and a genesis.block. I have read the documentation, watched tutorials and looked on the internet but I still don't understand why the genesis.block and channel.tx is needed an why it's created like this. For example: shouldn't the genesis.block be in the blockchain including the channel configuration?

Answer (score 2):

A simplified answer:

A **genesis block** is referred to as the *first* block.

The first (genesis) block in a channel, is a **channel.tx** (channel configuration transaction). It doesn't contain much more than the name of the channel, and the *consortium* that is allowed to use the channel.

The **orderer genesis block** is what configures an orderer when it starts. It contains MSP IDs for each organization, which MSP IDs are part of a consortium, and a trusted certificate for each MSP ID.

The orderer needs information about organizations, because **the orderer approves the creation of new channels**. A channel creation request must come from a trusted entity (part of an organization), or else the channel will not be created.

Since you cannot modify (execute a transaction) in a channel without an orderer approving, it makes sense to only let the orderer have the network information. This way you don't risk having inconsistent information between channels/orderers in case anything changes.

All Fabric blocks are encoded/serialized using protobuf, as the internal communication relies on gRPC. A block is thus in a **binary** format.

Answer (score 0):

Think like this, what would you do if you want to change the configuration of the blockchain system? shutdown all the host, edit their config and restart them one by one? That will be rediculous, because we say that blockchain is decentralized, nobody can control all the hosts. The only way to change configurarion dynamically is consensus online. So how to make consensus online, obviously, the answer is using transactions(tx). As for the initialization of the blockchain in frabric, we can use the same way , that is channel.tx and genesis.block, to eliminating the cost of initialization by reuse the logic of editting configuration. Meanwhile, tx should be placed in a block, so that is why genesis.block exist.

Comment: thank you for your response. I understand the concept of concensus in relation with configuration. But what I don't understand is what the channel.tx includes? For what is it used? For channel configuration? And what about the network configuration? There is no file for that anywhere.. Hope you can help me out!

Comment: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html You can find some information in this website. I recommend you to read byfn.sh in the sample given by fabric.  And what contained in channel.tx is generated by configtx.yaml, which is some kind of file easy to read and understand.